# Openshift : application directory gets empty after creating a persistent volume

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-origin

i have a java application that is working fine on Openshift. However i need to create a persistent volume in order to store the logs and some data of this app. The logs and the data are exported in the same directory where the jar is located. I created a persistent volume claim and mounted it to the app directory in the container like so:

```
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /app
  name: app-volume
volumes:
- name: app-volume
  persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: app-pvc
```

After mounting the volume i the container crashes because it doesn't find the jar file. When i take a look inside the container the /app directory is really empty.

when i unmount the persistent volume or create one in another path than where the jar located the application works fine

Is it not possible in Openshift to have a persistent volume in the same directory where the application located ? Or why is the directory getting empty.

[image: container]

Comment: The content of the directory, where a persistent volume is mounted, indeed is replaced with the content of the persistent volume. You can theoretically store your application in the persistent volume, however that is not usual. Normally, one would create custom directory for persistent data and have the volume mounted there.

Comment: @JiriFiala Do you know a good reference where i can understand how the synchronization between the local directory volume and remote volume works ? Like when which volume gets overwritten ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but you can't access anything else than the volume content in the respective directory (mount) path. More details on how persistent works can be found int [OpenShift documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/architecture/additional_concepts/storage.html). Also [this interactive course](https://learn.openshift.com/introduction/transferring-files/) may answer a few questions.